# Storing videos in Youtube

Tags: php, video, youtube, storage

I am actually developing a website that allow users to upload videos of 30 seconds.
I was wondering if there was any other posibility for the storage than using my own space. I don't know if storing is expensive, so I was wondering if there was any posibility uploading the video from my website to youtube.
The video would be hosted in my channel and I should only have to store the URL in my website database.
This is the schema i've designed to do that:

https://scontent-a-cdg.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn2/t1.0-9/10013682_10202355685148152_2120989987_n.jpg

For uploading and conecting with the database I am using PHP + MySQLi.
I figure the response of youtube to any video petition is relative lower and the main advantage is I don't overclock my website.

I also wonder if it is possible to do the same with pictures, like i had planned using Facebook with OAuth 2.0.

Waiting your answers/suggestions and thanking you so much for your patience and attention.

Dev

Comment: How about Google Drive? Various sites currently use it for video - https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2424384?hl=en

Comment: You're going to need [Youtube's API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/) I believe. Same for Facebook. Downside is then they control the content, how it's displayed, and if they decide to take down your account, good-bye data! I don't know what your hosting plan is like but you can pick up more storage and bandwidth at reasonable prices. Plus, you can avoid giving even more power to the Internet juggernauts and support an open, decentralized web :)

Comment: Thank you so much for all the answers. I'll take in consideration all you guys told me.